# invalid use of member (did you forget the «&» ?)

Tags: c++, class, gtk

sample code .h

```
class My {
public:
    My();
    ~My();
    void Quit();
private:
};
```

sample code .cpp

```
void My::Quit()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}

My::My()
{
    ...

    item = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Quit");
    gtk_widget_show(item);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), item);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(item), "activate", G_CALLBACK(this->Quit), NULL);

    ...
}
```

getting error: invalid use of member (did you forget the «&» ?)

What is my problem?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the full error message?

Comment: This is the complete error message ..

Comment: The complete error message would include the line number and sometimes even the line in question.  From your question we have to guess where in your source code the error is.

Answer (score 5):

`this->Quit` isn't a valid expression; it can only be used to call the function directly.

The syntax for taking the address of a member function is `&My::Quit`.

The function will have to be a static member or non-member to be used as a callback.